# URL in Client's Browser cannot updated

Tags: php

Currently I am using PHP to build a Web Management Portal for my client.

After the portal user login, I have redirect the page corresponding to the user right and the problem occurred after we used the domain name to access the web portal

**Expected result:**

```
 http//MY_SERVER_IP/Login/ -> Auth success -> redirect to http//MY_SERVER_IP/CONTENT/
```

In the browser, we can see the address showed `"http//MY_SERVER_IP/CONTENT/"`after login

**But problem occurred after using domain:**

```
 "http//www_MY_DOMAIN_com" mapped to "http//MY SERVER IP/Login/" using url frame
```

*"http//www_MY_DOMAIN_com" -> Auth success -> redirect to the page successfully*

BUT In the browser, it always shows `"http//www_MY_DOMAIN_com"` ONLY.
Therefore, when the user click F5 button to refresh the page, the page is always go back to Login page.

If I want the user staying in *"http//www_MY_DOMAIN_com/content/"*, is that possible?

how to change the browser bar address to *"http//www_MY_DOMAIN_com/content/"*, not always staying in `"http//www_MY_DOMAIN_com"`?

thanks for help

Comment: If you're using an iframe then it's normal that the address bar isn't updated.

Comment: @ André Daniel I mean it wrong. Yes, It is iframe/redirect problem. I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of using frames. If you load a URL into a frame and that URL redirects, then the new URL will still be loaded into the frame.

If you want to break out of them then you'll need to do so explicitly.

Set up DNS to point to your actual server instead of using frame based domain hosting.

Comment: Hi Quentin, thanks for you reply, I will try to set up DNS for this.